# Interfaces en Java

Tags: java, herencia, interfaz

Buenas noches a todos.

Continuo con la aventura de aprender Java, actualmente intento resolver un ejercicio de interfaces y herencia:

Problema:
En la escuela de informática Río Grande desea mejorar la eficiencia el sistema escolar, al cual 3 tipos de usuario tienen acceso: Maestro, Alumno y Tutor, cada uno de ellos tiene las siguientes características:

-Maestro

- Id
- nombre
- apellido
- correoElectronico
  *imprimirPerfil() el cual mostrará los datos básicos de la cuenta (Id, nombre, apellido, correo electrónico

-Alumno

- Id
- nombre
- apellido
- calificacion
- correoElectronico
- imprimirPerfil() el cual mostrará los datos básicos de la cuenta (Id, nombre, apellido, correo electrónico)
- mostrarCalificaciones(), mostrará su calificación
- guardarCalificacion(calificacion)

-Tutor

- Id
- nombre
- apellido
- correoElectronico
- alumno
- imprimirPerfil() el cual mostrará los datos básicos de la cuenta (Id, nombre, apellido, correo electrónico)
- mostrarCalificaciones(), mostrará la calificación del alumno

También deberás simular las acciones de base de datos y mostrar los datos con impresión en consola.
El proyecto debe de contener: herencia, métodos, uso de variables, uso de modificadores de acceso, paso de variables, encapsulamiento, retorno de valores, clase abstracta e interfaz.

He realizado lo siguiente:

```
public abstract class Perfiles {
public String id;
public String nombre;
public String apellido;
public String correoElectronico;
 

Perfiles (String id, String nombre, String apellido, String correoElectronico){
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.correoElectronico = correoElectronico;
}

public String getid(){
    return this.id;
}

public String getnombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public String getapellido (){
    return this.apellido;
}

public String getcorreoElectronico(){
    return this.correoElectronico;
}
```

---

```
interface IPerfil {

public void imprimirPerfil();

}
```

---

```
public interface ICalificaciones {


public void mostrarCalificaciones();
public void guardarCalificacion();

}
```

---

```
public class Maestro extends Perfiles
 implements IPerfil{

Maestro(String id, String nombre, String apellido, String correoElectronico){
    super (id,nombre, apellido, correoElectronico);
}

@Override
 public void imprimirPerfil() {
   System.out.println("ID :" + this.id);
   System.out.println("Nombre :" + this.nombre);
   System.out.println("Apellido :" + this.apellido);
   System.out.println("Correo: " + this.correoElectronico);
 }

}
```

---

```
public class Alumno extends Perfiles
implements IPerfil, ICalificaciones{

Alumno(String id, String nombre, String apellido, String correoElectronico){
    super (id,nombre, apellido, correoElectronico);
}

@Override
 public void imprimirPerfil() {
   System.out.println("ID :" + this.id);
   System.out.println("Nombre :" + this.nombre);
   System.out.println("Apellido :" + this.apellido);
   System.out.println("Correo: " + this.correoElectronico);
}

@Override 
public void mostrarCalificaciones(){
    System.out.println();
}

@Override
public void guardarCalificacion(){
    
}
    
}
```

---

```
public class Tutor extends Perfiles
implements IPerfil, ICalificaciones{
Tutor(String id, String nombre, String apellido, String correoElectronico){
    super (id,nombre, apellido, correoElectronico);
}

@Override
public void imprimirPerfil() {
   System.out.println("ID :" + this.id);
   System.out.println("Nombre :" + this.nombre);
   System.out.println("Apellido :" + this.apellido);
   System.out.println("Correo: " + this.correoElectronico);
}

@Override 
public void mostrarCalificaciones(){
    System.out.println();
}

@Override
public void guardarCalificacion(){}

}
```

---

```
public class Test {
public static void main (String[] args){
    
    Maestro maestro = new Maestro ("M123", "Alejandro", "Ramírez", "maestro123@riogrande.com"); 
    maestro.imprimirPerfil();


    Alumno alumno = new Alumno ("A951", "Diana", "López", "alumno951@riogrande.com");
    alumno.imprimirPerfil();
    alumno.mostrarCalificaciones();
    alumno.guardarCalificacion();
    
    Tutor tutor = new Tutor ("T456", "Julian", "Sánchez", "tutor456@riogrande.com");
    tutor.imprimirPerfil();
    tutor.mostrarCalificaciones();

 }
}
```

---

El problema que tengo es que no logro implementar los métodos:

*mostrarCalificaciones(), mostrará su calificación; para el perfil Alumno y Tutor.

*guardarCalificacion(calificacion), con este método se debe guardar la calificación del alumno; para el perfil Alumno.

Además de que, para el perfil de Tutor se debe asociar un Alumno e imprimir su calificación con el método: mostrarCalificaciones(), mostrará su calificación.

¿Qué modificaciones podría realizar al código para poder ejecutarlo de esta manera?

Agradezco sus comentarios, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches primero que nada lo que veo de tu clase es que tienes varios errores en cuanto a POO se refiere.

Lo primero cuando te hablan de encapsulamiento es que solo puede ser accedido por la misma clase y no por alguien más. En las dos clases que tienes las propiedades pueden ser editadas en cualquier parte del programa, yo te invito a que en vez de public a las propiedades las pongas privadas, y generes sus métodos getters y setters ya que será con estos métodos con los que puedas acceder. desde cualquier otra clase.

Lo siguiente que veo es si vas a tener métodos que guarden y muestren deben de recibir algún parámetro, yo le crearía al profesor una propiedad nota. para que el pueda registrar la nota del alumno (También deberías de ver cuantas notas vas a guardar y como y para ello usarías un arreglo o una lista). En mostrar calificaciones retornas un double o un int no vació.

Para imprimir el Perfil es mejor utilizar un toString en vez de tantos System.out.println.

En los perfiles deberías usar sobrecarga de constructores pues el profesor tendrá un tipo de perfil y el alumno y el tutor otro.

Espero que estos consejos te puedan orientar un poco en el camino.

Comment: Intente seguir tu sugerencia, de momento me tope con que no me permite imprimir los parámetros ya que indica que son privados, ¿Qué hice incorrecto?

Comment: Para acceder a una propiedad sí ya creaste los métodos getters y setters, debes llamar a dichos métodos para ver la propiedad.